A problem about Branching process in Durrett

This problem comes from Durrett, 5th edition,p231:

Background:Let $Z_n$ be a branching process with offspring distribution $p_k$ i.e. $$Z_{n+1}=\begin{cases}\xi_1^{n+1}+\cdots+\xi_{Z_n}^{n+1}&\text{if }Z_n>0\\0&\text{if }Z_n=0\end{cases}$$where $\xi_i^n$ are i.i.d and $p_k = P(\xi_i^n = k)$ is the offspring distribution.
Denote $m=\mathbb E[\xi_i^n]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp_k$

Question:When $m=1$ and $p_1=\mathbb P\big(\xi_i^l = 1\big) < 1$,given
$p\in \mathbb N_+$and $N\in \mathbb N_+$,prove
that:$$\begin{aligned}P(Z_n=p,\forall n\ge N)=0\end{aligned}$$

Here is my attempt:$$\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z_N=p,Z_{N+1}=p)&=\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{Z_{N-1}}\xi_{j}^{N-1}=p,\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p)\\&=\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{Z_{N-1}}\xi_{j}^{N-1}=p)\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p)\\&=\mathbb P(Z_N=p)\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p) 
\end{align}$$where the second equality is deduced by independence of $(\xi_j^n)$.
So I am trying to prove that:$$\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p) <1$$Once this inequality is true$$\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z_N=p,Z_{N+1}=p,Z_{N+2}=p)&=\mathbb P(Z_{N+2}=p|Z_{N+1}=p,Z_{N}=p)\mathbb P(Z_{N+1}=p,Z_{N}=p)\\&=\mathbb P(Z_{N+2}=p|Z_{N+1}=p)\mathbb P(Z_N=p)\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p)\\&=\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N+1}=p) \mathbb P(Z_N=p)\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p)
\end{align}$$And since $\xi_i^n$ are i.i.d $\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N+1}=p)=\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p)$,we can conclude that:$$\mathbb P(Z_N=p,Z_{N+1}=p,Z_{N+2}=p)= \mathbb P(Z_N=p)\big(\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p)\big)^2$$By applying this process repeatedly $$\mathbb P(Z_N=p,..,Z_{N+l}=p)= \mathbb P(Z_N=p)\big(\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p)\big)^l$$Let $l\to \infty$ we get the result we want.
But I am stuck at proving that:$$\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^{N}=p) <1$$Is this inequality right?I think we should use the condition $m=1$ here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Consider $p$ independent Branching processes $(Z^1_m),\ldots, (Z^p_m)$ with  the same distribution as $(Z_n)$ and independent of $(Z_n).$ Clearly
$$(Z_{N+m})|\{Z_N=p\}\sim ((Z^1_m+\cdots+Z^p_m))=(S_m).$$ Therefore
$$\Pr(\{(Z_{N+m}=p\ \forall \ m>0)\}\cap \{Z_N=p\})$$$$=\Pr(\{(S_{N+m}=p\ \forall \ m>0)\}|Z_N=p)\Pr(Z_N=p)$$$$=\Pr(Z_N=p)\Pr(\{(S_{m}=0\ \forall \ m>0)\leq \Pr(Z_N=p)\Pr(\{(S_{m}=0\ \forall \ 0<m\leq M)$$$$=\Pr(Z_N=p)p_0^{pM}\to_{M\to \infty} 0$$ since $0<1-p_1=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}np_n$ implies the existence of some $n_0\geq 2$ such that $p_{n_0}>0$. Hence $0\leq p_0\leq 1-p_{n_0}<1.$
Edit: Oh, apologies, I have mixed $Z_n$ and the progeny $P_n=Z_0+Z_1+\cdots+Z_n.$ Now, to answer  your question: for all $M$ we have $$\Pr(Z_n=p\ \forall n\geq N)\leq \Pr(0=Z_{N+1}-Z_N=Z_{N+2}-Z_{N+1}=\ldots=Z_{N+M+1}-Z_{N+M})=p_0^M\to_{M\to\infty}0$$ since $p_0<1$ as shown above.

Could you explain why you consider another p independent Branching processes such that they are all distributed to $Z_n,\forall n?$And I am still confused about $(Z_{N+m})|{Z_N=p}\sim((Z_m^1+\cdots+Z_m^p))=(S_m)$,did you mean ,for instance,m=1,$Pr(Z_{N+1}=k|Z_N=p)=Pr(Z_1^1+..+Z_1^p=k),\forall k$?If so,it is still hard for to check this equlity.

See edit. Since we are in the case $m=1$ we have $Z_n\to 0$ But I realise that your question was just for proving it!

Thank you!Your answer provides a more direct proof.Now I totally understand how to solve my question.

Denote $\mathbb P(\xi^m_i=k)=\mu(k),k=0,1,2..$.If $\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^N= p)=1$ then $\mathbb P(\sum_{j=1}^{p}\xi_{j}^N\neq p)=0$.Especially $\mu(0)=0$.But then $\mu(0)+\mu(1)+\mu(2)+..=1$ and $\mu(1)+2\mu(2)+..=m=1$ leads to $\mu(n)=0,n\ge 2$. Hence $\mu(1)=1$ contrading the fact that $\mu(1)<1$
